# CSS loads but doesn't do anything

Tags: html, css, node.js, p5.js, httpserver

I'm trying to make a basic multiplayer game with Socket.IO, p5.js and NodeJS, hosting it on Replit.

I have a basic `httpServer` with `socket.io`, and it serves the HTML, CSS and JavaScript files fine. But when I put the `<link>` tag in the HTML to load the CSS, the CSS loads fine (I can see it in the *Sources* tab in the Chrome DevTools) but it doesn't actually apply to the HTML.

The code is [here](https://replit.com/@LuisAFK/Multiplayer-Online-IO-Game-2), but I'll put it here as well.

`index.js` The main NodeJS file

```
const { readFileSync } = require('fs');
const { createServer } = require('http');
const { Server } = require('socket.io');

const httpServer = createServer((req, res) => {
  const r = /^\/?(index\.(html|css|js))?$/i;

  if (!r.test(req.url))
  {
    res.writeHead(404);
    res.end('Not found');

    return;
  }

  const m = req.url.match(r);

  // reload the file every time
  const content = readFileSync(__dirname + '/public/' + (m[1] || 'index.html'));
  const length = Buffer.byteLength(content);

  res.writeHead(200, {
    'Content-Type': 'text/html',
    'Content-Length': length,
  });
  res.end(content);
});

const io = new Server(httpServer, {
  // Socket.IO options
});

let players = {};

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  players[socket.id] = {
    id: socket.id,
    x: 0,
    y: 0
  };

  socket.on('disconnect', (reason) => {
    delete players[socket.id];
  });
});

io.on('data', data => {
  players[data.id].x += data.x;
  players[data.id].y += data.y;
});

setInterval(() => {
  io.sockets.emit('data', players);
}, 1000 / 60);

httpServer.listen(6001);
```

---

`public/index.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <title>Multiplayer Online IO Game 2</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">

  <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.4.0/p5.min.js" integrity="sha512-N4kV7GkNv7QR7RX9YF/olywyIgIwNvfEe2nZtfyj73HdjCUkAfOBDbcuJ/cTaN04JKRnw1YG1wnUyNKMsNgg3g==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
  <script src="/index.js" defer></script>
</head>
<body>
  
</body>
</html>
```

---

`public/index.css`

```
body
{
  margin: 0px;

  overflow: hidden;
}

canvas
{
  display: none;
}
```

The canvas' `display: none` was to see if the CSS actually did anything, but it doesn't.

---

`public/index.js` The client JavaScript

```
let ID = null;
let players = {};

const socket = io({
  // Socket.IO options
});

socket.on('connect', () => {
  ID = socket.id;
});

socket.on('connect_error', (err) => {
  alert(`There was an error connecting to the WebSocket server:\n${err.message}`);
});

socket.on('data', (data) => {
  players = data;
});

function setup()
{
  createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight);
}

function draw()
{
  background(255);

  fill(0);

  for (const id of Object.keys(players))
  {
    const player = players[id];

    circle(player.x, player.y, 10);
  }
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your server is using the content type `text/html` for all responses regardless of the type of file being returned. Some web browsers are strict about content-types and will not process a stylesheet if it has the wrong content type. Here's a example fix:

```js
const httpServer = createServer((req, res) => {
  const r = /^\/?(index\.(html|css|js))?$/i;

  if (!r.test(req.url))
  {
    res.writeHead(404);
    res.end('Not found');

    return;
  }

  const m = req.url.match(r);

  // reload the file every time
  const content = readFileSync(__dirname + '/public/' + (m[1] || 'index.html'));
  const length = Buffer.byteLength(content);

  res.writeHead(200, {
    // Determine the content type based on the file extension
    'Content-Type': m[2] ? getContentType(m[2]) : 'text/html',
    'Content-Length': length,
  });
  res.end(content);
});

function getContentType(ext) {
  switch (ext.toLowerCase()) {
    case 'html':
      return 'text/html';
    case 'css':
      return 'text/css';
    case 'js':
      return 'text/javascript';
    default:
      return 'application/octet-stream';
  }
}
```

You might want to consider using a more full-featured HTTP server such as [express](https://expressjs.com/) instead of rolling your own.